# Retrieve HTML element from webview on click

Tags: android, webview

I'm facing an issue with Android's webview.

I'm trying to get the HTML Element from a webview (for example, a field to complete).

I don't have any hand on the displayed webview, I'm just a consummer.

I have try some answers from stack over flow (onTouchListener, injection of JS code, addJavascriptInterface,...), but nothing works. With the "hitTestResult", I'm only facing "null" when I click somewhere inside the webview (even if this is a field to complete).

Do you know how to retrieve the HTML element ?

Thanks you.

Edit: 
I have modified a lot my code, so for now, it looks like :

First, I bind my view :

```
binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

And I load my webview :

```
binding.webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?
    ): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
}
binding.webView.setOnTouchListener { view, event ->
    val hr = (view as WebView).hitTestResult
    Log.i("LOG", "getExtra = " + hr.extra + "Type= " + hr.type)
    false
}
```

I have also try : 
(inside "shouldOverrideUrlLoading", I have never see any toast)

```
view?.addJavascriptInterface(object : Any() {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun performClick() {
        Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked")
        Toast.makeText(this@MyActivity, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}, "test")
```

In the WebViewClient object (when I have done this, I've set javaScriptEnabled and domStorageEnabled to true), but no callback :

```
override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url)

    Log.d("TAG", "test tag")
    view?.evaluateJavascript(addMyClickCallBackJs(), null)
    view?.evaluateJavascript(test(), null)
}
```

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun onData(value: String?) {
    print("value")
}

@JavascriptInterface
fun myClick(idOrClass: String) {
    Log.d("TAG", "myClick-> $idOrClass")
}

fun addMyClickCallBackJs(): String? {
    var js = "javascript:"
    js += "function myClick(event){" +
    "if(event.target.className == null){my.myClick(event.target.id)}" +
    "else{my.myClick(event.target.className)}}"
    js += "document.addEventListener(\"click\",myClick,true);"
    return js
}

fun test(): String {
    return "javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.getElementById('*');"+
    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
    "})()"
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying that isn't working? We can't see the code you've tried, so if you can show us what steps you followed that failed we can see the issue better.

Comment: @RedBassett Thanks for your quick answer, I've edited the first message to add some informations, I will try to find all things I have done until now to be more specific